# how to run two functions simultaneously inside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

I have two functions inside "componentDidMount" each function reads sensor's values and send it to the backend(flask), one of the functions are way faster than the other, although it shouldn't be that way.
how can I manage to send the values from the two functions at the same time ( in parallel) ? so let's say I receive 40 values in the backend each second, I want almost 20 of those values to be from the first function and the renaming 20 to be from the second function

```
componentDidMount() {
SensorManager.startAccelerometer(30); // To start the accelerometer with a minimum delay of 50ms between events.
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("Accelerometer",function(data) {
  fetch("http://192.168.1.107:5000/api/or", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      accelerometer: data
    })
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      console.log("hello");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});

SensorManager.startOrientation(50);
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("Orientation",function(data) {
  fetch("http://192.168.1.107:5000/api/or", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      orientation: data
    })
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      console.log("hello");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});
}
```

Comment: They _do_ run simultaneously. (Actually, they run concurrent, but I assume that's what you meant...)

Comment: usually for each second I receive like 20 values from the second function ( orientation) and almost only 5 values from the first function ( Accelerometer ) so I don't think it's working in parallel

Comment: You can do some benchmark tests to confirm the speeds of each function but to answer your question this code snippet indicates that they are running simultaneously. Maybe you should consider going async?

Answer (score 0):

This only depends on the events you listen. If you want something cleaner, don't use listeners. Use getters and do it in a loop like:

```js
setInterval(() => {
   getAccelerometer()
   fetch('accelerometer params')
   getOrientation()
   fetch('orientation params')
}, 100)
```

Comment: it's a npm package and that's how the function works, can I call the function the way I want ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a callback when each of these two separate events happen. Instead of immediately making API requests (per event)--you could try to store that data temporarily and write logic to manage your POST requests more evenly.

First event fires => Store the accelerometer data. If data for orientation already exists => make two POST requests (and vice versa).

Switching to async/await might be more readable if you're going to incorporate logic to couple the requests together.

I agree that benchmark tests/reviewing the documentation might point at why these requests are so drastically different in timing. The API was built to manage the requests separately, so just be sure that you can count on an orientation event for every accelerometer event--or at least gracefully handle the error.

Comment: thanks for your help, the problem is I need to read at least 20 values from each sensor each second, and send it to flask to pass it to another function, and it's working in real time

Comment: Absolutely. Well, regardless of requests per second, you could still write async logic to couple the requests or at least run some checks during the event callback. Best of luck!